# Python: Remove top 'n' keys from a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary dict. For each key in dict, there is a list, that has two items in it. One is another dictionary, the other is an integer.

```
dict = {
    'hello' : [
      {
         'blah' : 1,
         'dodo' : 2
      },
      3
    ],
    'world' : [
      {
         'foo' : 7,
         'bar' : 1
      },
      8
    ]
 }
```

I want to sort the dictionary dict on the second item in the list, the integer. And then remove the first 'n' keys from the dictionary. Is there any way to do it? The sorted function works only on lists.

Here is the function I'm trying to do this in.

```
def create_inverted_index(inverted_index, corpus_tokens, corpus_files):
for file_tokens in corpus_tokens:
    file_id = corpus_files[file_tokens[0]]
    for token in file_tokens[1]:
        if token in inverted_index.keys():
            inverted_index[token][1] += 1
            if file_id in inverted_index[token][0].keys():
                inverted_index[token][0][file_id] += 1
            else:
                inverted_index[token][0][file_id] = 1
        else:
            inverted_index[token] = [{file_id : 1}, 1]
```

Comment: Is that your actual dict? I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` when I try to run it.

Comment: @Kevin seems like the two keys for the main dict are missing.

Comment: Can you post working code please?

Comment: @khelwood I've added the function in the post. The code is working fine, I just want to sort the dictionary.

Comment: @Kevin The keys were missing in the dictionary. Edited.

Comment: What do you mean *"sort the dictionary"*? Dictionaries are *unordered*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, so in this example, world should be ranked above hello, as the integer value of world is 8 and that of hello is 3. I know dictionaries are unordered, but I HAVE to remove the first 'n' largest values from it.

Comment: `dict`s are not sortable. and you should never name something that shadows a built-in (i.e. don't name it `dict`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by doing this:

```
d = {1: [1, 2], 3: [2,4], 4:[3,3], 2:[4,1], 0:[5,0]} # dict to remove items from

sorted_list=sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
sorted_keys = [key[1] for key in sorted_list]

n=2 # number of items to remove
for key in sorted_keys[0:n]:
    d = dict([(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if v != key ])
```

This code copies the dict to a list ordered by the second item in dict values. Then it creates a list with only the sorted keys and iterate over it removing them as values from the dictionary.

For my value of d and `n=3`, output is:

```
{3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 3]}
```

For n=2:

```
{1: [1, 2], 3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 3]}
```

Ps: Might not be most efficient way of doing this, but does the job

Answer (score 1):

In Python, dictionaries don't have an order. You cannot sort a `dict`. However, you can take a look at [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: As of Python 3.7, dictionaries are ordered (but not necessarily sorted).